# Model in Laravel Observer does not match the database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-lighthouse

I have an observer set up for when a `user` instance is saved. However, the model instance passed into the observer method consists of data prior to the database insertion. The event is triggered by running a GraphQL mutation via Lighthouse. If I manually set the user's groups and save it, the observer performs as expected.

Here's an example that sets a user's groups:

```
mutation {
  updateUser(input: {
    id: 1
    groups: {
      sync: [1]
    }
  }) {
    groups { id }
  }
}
```

Currently my `UserObserver::saved` looks like:

```
public function saved(User $user)
{
    // Shows the groups prior to the update
    dump($user->groups->toArray());

    // Even a raw query doesn't get the updated groups
    dump(DB::select('select * from group_user where userId=1'));
}
```

This is using Laravel 5.8.35 and Lighthouse 4.6

Comment: If you do `$user = $user->fresh();`, does it pick up the change afterwards?

Comment: @ceejayoz it does not

Comment: Scratching my head here; are there transactions involved?

Comment: @ceejayoz nope, just a simple relationship association, then a save call.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reload the relationships of your `$user` instance, you have several ways to do this:

1. Call `refresh()` method after save, which reloads the current model instance with fresh attributes and all eager-loaded relationships from the database:

   - `$user->refresh();`
2. Manually reload all your loaded relationships after save:

   - `$user->load(collect($user->getRelations())->except('pivot')->keys()->toArray());`
3. Manually reload your specific relationship after save:

   - `$user->load('groups');`

Call any of this on top of your saved observer function:

```php
public function saved(User $user)
{
    // re-eager-load `groups` relationship 
    $user->load('groups');
    dump($user->groups->toArray());
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what I do, the Observer never has the most recent data. Even if I do a raw DB query, it's like the Observer is executing before the SQL is committed.

Comment: @Nathan you are calling any of this on top of your `saved` observer function before `dump($user->groups->toArray()` and nothing changes?

Comment: @Nathan would you please post your `saved` method? also the way you're saving your instance may help finding the issue.

Comment: @Nathan your raw query for test seems wrong, shouldn't it be: `select * from group_user where user_id=1` instead?

Comment: Ah, yeah, that was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `groups` relationship is a `BelongsToMany` one? So, when the User is `saved`, the groups are not synced already, because in the background it does something like this:

```
$user = User::create($args); // Saved event dispatched
$user->groups()->sync($args['groups']['sync']); // The groups are synced here
```

So, I think you may want to use [`@event`](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.7/api-reference/directives.html#event)

Comment: Groups is a `BelongsToMany`, however it's being set and then saved. This used to work fine and suddenly it didn't. Even with a raw query in the observer, the data returned is always old.